# JavaScript timer | Random behavior

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval, oracle-adf

I have a requirement to display a popup after a certain interval, where a countdown timer runs for 5 mins, and if there is no interaction until the countdown becomes 0:00, it redirects to a certain url. I have written the following js function for this but it is buggy at times the timer runs in negative or stops executing! Here is the code -

```
function displayOnTimeOut() {
    window.docTitle = document.title;
    var outputText = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('root:popupTxt');
    outputText.setValue(' ');
    var timerInitDate = new Date();
    var endTime = timerInitDate.getMinutes() * 60 + timerInitDate.getSeconds() + 300;
    function displayCountdown() {
        var d = new Date();
        var timeNow = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds();
        var timeleft = endTime - timeNow;
        var seconds = timeleft % 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(timeleft / 60);
        var minutesText = " minutes";
        if (minutes == 1) {
            minutesText = " minute";
        }
        var secondsText = " seconds";
        if (seconds == 1) {
            secondsText = " second";
        }
        if (seconds > 1 && seconds % 2 == 0) {
            document.title = document.title == docTitle ? 'News Flash' : docTitle;
        }
        if (timeleft == 0) {
            clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            outputText.setValue(' ');
            window.location.href = '/some/url.jspx';
            return;
        } else {
            outputText.setValue(minutes + minutesText + " and " + seconds + secondsText);
        }
    }
    window.timerIntervalId = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000);
    var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('root:popup');
    popup.show();
}
var timeOutPeriod = 60 * 1000;
if (typeof timerTimeoutId !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(timerTimeoutId);
}
if (typeof timerIntervalId !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(timerIntervalId);
}
window.timerTimeoutId = setTimeout(displayOnTimeOut, timeOutPeriod);
```

Please ignore how / when this is called, I invoke it using `ExtendedRenderKitService` when required. 
I'm not too much of an expert in JS coding as it would be evident by the above code, please can someone have a look?

Much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `if (timeleft <= 0)`

Comment: Thanks lujcon, however, I am invoking `clearInterval` if `timeleft` becomes `0`, so it should never be less than 0, isn't it? also added the `return` statement for this.

Comment: It's not true. setInterval every 1 second doesn't mean that it will be executed every second. It can be every 1001 ms... so you can have 1 second left and with next iteration -1 second left...

Comment: But sometimes the timer stops as well, but there is no error - it just gets stuck at a random value. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is 'not the best'. Instead of counting seconds (it will not work this way you have implemented it) just make `timeleft = endTime-d//date diff in ms`.

Comment: `var endTime = new Date(timerInitDate.getTime() + 5*60000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function displayOnTimeOut() {
    window.docTitle = document.title;
    var outputText = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('root:popupTxt');
    outputText.setValue(' ');
    var timerInitDate = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date(timerInitDate.getTime() + 5*60000)
    function displayCountdown() {
        var timeNow = new Date();
        var timeleft = endTime - timeNow;

        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            outputText.setValue(' ');
            window.location.href = '/some/url.jspx';
            return;
        }

        var minutes = Math.floor(timeleft / 60000);
        var seconds = Math.floor(((timeleft % 60000) / 1000));

        var minutesText = " minutes";
        if (minutes == 1) {
            minutesText = " minute";
        }
        var secondsText = " seconds";
        if (seconds == 1) {
            secondsText = " second";
        }
        if (seconds > 1 && seconds % 2 == 0) {
            document.title = document.title == docTitle ? 'News Flash' : docTitle;
        }

        outputText.setValue(minutes + minutesText + " and " + seconds + secondsText);
    }
    window.timerIntervalId = setInterval(displayCountdown, 1000);
    var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('root:popup');
    popup.show();
}
var timeOutPeriod = 60 * 1000;
if (typeof timerTimeoutId !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(timerTimeoutId);
}
if (typeof timerIntervalId !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(timerIntervalId);
}
window.timerTimeoutId = setTimeout(displayOnTimeOut, timeOutPeriod);
```

Comment: Thanks, final question though - 
why `toFixed` and not `Math.round`. `toFixed` behaves differently on different browsers. Also I couldn't understand what difference it would make using date objects here, can you please explain?

Comment: If you use `getMinutes` you'll get wrong values. Imagine time 10:58. getMinutes gives you 58, end time will be 63! but timeNow after 5 minutes will give you 3. getMinutes returns minutes part of the time. It's relative to an current hour. If the hour changes - you are getting wrong results.

Comment: And you are right. toFixed is not the best one as it returns string.